# How do I change to the new server version?

Tags: debian, postgresql-13, postgresql-14

I have versions 13 and 14 of postgres installed on my system. When I start the server using `systemctl start postgresql` it always starts version 13.

The client application shows version 14.

```
# psql -V
psql (PostgreSQL) 14.1 (Debian 14.1-1.pgdg100+1)
```

But the database tells me the server running is version 13.

```
# select version ();
                                                     version                                                      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 13.5 (Debian 13.5-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

I found the file `/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service` but it refers to the version as the variable `%I`. There is a comment at the top of the file that says:

```
# variable %i expands to "version-cluster", %I expands to "version/cluster".
```

What sets that version number? How do I get it to start version 14 when I run `systemctl start postgresql`? Ideally, I would like to know how to switch back and forth between versions.

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: I am running Debian 10.11.